# Add timestamp to zip created by sbt-native-packager

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Would it be possible to append a timestamp to the generated zip's filename you get when executing the `dist` command?

Lets say my project name is "backend", and the current dev version is 0.2.3-SNAPSHOT. What I would like to do is execute the `dist` command and get a file called backend-0.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20150506.zip.
However, I only want to append the timestamp when doing `dist` on a snapshot version, not a production version (0.2.3 for example).

I'm using Play 2.4.0-RC1 and sbt 0.13.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

 packageName in Universal := {
   val name = (packageName in Universal).value
   def timestamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd") format new java.util.Date()
   if (isSnapshot.value) s"$name-$timestamp" else name
 }
```

---

Here's what `dist` does with `version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"` and `version := "1.0"` (removing some noise):

```
 [play-scala] $ dist
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
 [info] Wrote /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-web-assets.jar ...
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
 [info]
 [info] Your package is ready in /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/universal/play-scala-1.0-SNAPSHOT-20150506.zip

 [play-scala] $ set version := "1.0"
 [info] Defining *:version

 [play-scala] $ dist
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-sources.jar ...
 [info] Wrote /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0.pom
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-web-assets.jar ...
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0-javadoc.jar ...
 [info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/scala-2.11/play-scala_2.11-1.0.jar ...
 [info]
 [info] Your package is ready in /Users/dnw/Desktop/play-scala/target/universal/play-scala-1.0.zip
```

Note that the jar file names aren't affected.

Comment: Perfect, nice and simple answer. Thank you!